# WAMP ignoring rewrite rules in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, wamp, apache2.4

I'm having trouble getting `mod_rewrite` to behave properly on WAMP after upgrading to PHP 7.0.0. All `RewriteRule`s seem to be completely ignored by Apache. They result in `404` errors.

This is my virtual host in `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myproject.local
    DocumentRoot "D:/Projects/myproject/www"
    ErrorLog "D:/Projects/myproject/www/apache_errors.log"
    LogLevel info

    <Directory  "D:/Projects/myproject/www/">
        LogLevel debug
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my `.htaccess`, which is recognized by Apache, will handle directives like `DirectoryIndex`, but seems to ignore any `RewriteRule`s:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_\-\s]+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA] #root pages
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_\-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z_\-\s]+)/?$ core/modules/$1/$2.php [L,QSA] #pages with no id
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_\-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z_\-\s]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ core/modules/$1/$2.php?$1_id=$3 [L,QSA] #pages with id (edit, etc)
```

My apache error log shows nothing of consequence: just that request fails:

```
[Sun Dec 18 15:47:03.787934 2016] [core:info] [pid 12532:tid 1140] [client ::1:57506] AH00128: File does not exist: D:/Projects/StoryTracker-Core/www/test
```

There must be some outside force I'm not aware of causing these results.

**EDIT**
I've updated my virtual host as follows to no avail:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myproject.local
    DocumentRoot "d:/projects/myproject/www"
    ErrorLog "d:/projects/myproject/www/apache_errors.log"
    LogLevel trace8

    <Directory  "d:/projects/myproject/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes

        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        LogLevel trace8             
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What happens if you disable `MultiViews`? It usually conflicts with rewriting. You should be using `END` instead of `L` on those rules, or adding `DPI`. Enable tracing for `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: @Walf I got this lone message when I attempted to access /contact/ The rewrite engine never picks up and rewrites the request. `[Mon Dec 19 22:36:52.661022 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 8204:tid 1116] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:55336] ::1 - - [myproject.local/sid#1fd26638ca0][rid#1fd291c9dd0/initial] [perdir D:/Projects/myproject/www/] pass through D:/Projects/myproject/www/contact`

Comment: I should get a `init rewrite engine with requested uri` then `applying pattern '^([a-zA-Z_\\-\\s]+)/?$' to uri '/contact/'`, but I don't know why the `init rewrite engine` never triggers

Answer (score 1):

`mod_rewrite` did not like dashes in my project directory name.

After renaming directories in my project path away from using `-`, I was able to figure out the rest of the issues from `LogLevel debug rewrite:trace8`.

Comment: Does adding the `-` back to the path immediately break it? Or do you know what steps trigger it? If so, you should file a bug report with the minimum code for it to be reproducible.